# Uploading an image to firebase storage only overrides current photo in SwiftUI/Swift 5?

Tags: swift, firebase, swiftui, firebase-storage

Coming to a problem where when I upload an image in my app to firebase storage it just overrides the current image I have on my storage. Like when I upload a new photo I want to show the new photo in my storage along with my old photo that is already in there. Can we do something with my code below? thanks for the help.

here is my code:

```
    struct UploadPhoto: View {
    @State var showActionSheet = false
    @State var showImagePicker = false
    
    @State var sourceType:UIImagePickerController.SourceType = .camera
    
    @State var upload_image:UIImage?
    @State var download_image:UIImage?
    
    @State private var showsAlert = false
     
    
    var body: some View {
       
        
      
        VStack {
            Text("Please upload your photos here!")
            HStack{
         
                if upload_image != nil {
                Image(uiImage: upload_image!)
                .resizable()
                .scaledToFit()
                    .frame(width:120, height:120, alignment: .center)
            } else {
                Image(systemName: "photo")
                .resizable()
                .scaledToFit()
                .frame(width:200, height:200, alignment: .center)
            }
 
            }.padding()
           
            Button(action: {
                self.showActionSheet = true
            }) {
                Text("Choose...")
            }.actionSheet(isPresented: $showActionSheet){
                ActionSheet(title: Text("Choose from camera or photo library..."), message: nil, buttons: [
                    //Button1
                    
                    .default(Text("Camera"), action: {
                        self.showImagePicker = true
                        self.sourceType = .camera
                    }),
                  
                    .default(Text("Photo Library"), action: {
                        self.showImagePicker = true
                        self.sourceType = .photoLibrary
                    }),
                    
                   
                    .cancel()
                    
                ])
            }.sheet(isPresented: $showImagePicker){
                imagePicker(image: self.$upload_image, showImagePicker: self.$showImagePicker, sourceType: self.sourceType)
                
            }
            
        
            Button(action: {
               
                if let thisImage = self.upload_image {
                    uploadImage(image: thisImage)
                 
                    
                } else {
                    
                    print("")
                }
                
                 
            }) {
              
                Text("Submit")
                 
                }
            }
 
        }
        
        
    }
    func uploadImage(image:UIImage){
        
        if let imageData = image.jpegData(compressionQuality: 1){
            
            let storage = Storage.storage()
            
            storage.reference().child("photo").putData(imageData, metadata: nil){
                (_, err) in
                if let err = err {
                 print("an error has occurred - \(err.localizedDescription)")
       }
                } else {
                     
                    print("Your photos have been successfully  
                }
            }
        } else {
            print("coldn't unwrap/case image to data")
        }
    }
 
 

struct UploadPhoto_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        UploadPhoto()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

When you upload an image to Firebase, you have to tell it the path where you want to save the image. In your code, you are putting the data to storage.reference().child("photo"). If you want to store multiple images, you need to change the "photo" path, otherwise it will overwrite the current image at the path. I would also recommend using sub-folders.

I would call something like:

```
let imageName = "image1"
let folderName = "folder1"
let path = "\(folderName)/\(imageName)"
storage.reference(withPath: path).putData...
```

Comment: I implement your snippet. However, it creates folder and then add image1 in it and then when I upload another one it overrides it.

Comment: You need to change the path (imageName and/or folderName) each time you call the function.

Comment: can we do it another way without me changing the path all the time?

Comment: No haha it's really for your benefit because when you download the images back from Firebase, you'll also need to specify the path where to download from. I would create another variable on the view and pass that variable into the path. Common practice would be to use some sort of ID as the folder name and then a descriptor for the photo. Something like "\(userID)/\(profilepicture)"

Comment: No problem.. let me know if you get stuck. Please mark as correct answer if it works :)

Comment: this answer not answer my question

Comment: Yes it is. You need to save the pictures with different paths.

Comment: am I going to change `let path = "\(folderName)/\(imageName)"` everytime I upload an image? if yes, I dont want it like that though

Comment: It's just a like a file you save to your computer. If you save a second file with the same name, it will overwrite the original file. If you want to save multiple files, you need to change the file name each time.